# Issue on simple xmlhttprequest with post data to expressjs

Tags: javascript, node.js, forms, express, xmlhttprequest

- Using nodejs, xmlhttprequest for simple Form post data.
- Using formdata() constructor to get the values from html.  But in
- expressjs, the request body is not getting properly. It throws the
  below error.  What would be the issue on posting data through the
  below code.

**Html**:

```
> <form id='loginForm'>
>       <div>
>         <label>Username:</label>
>         <input type="text" name="title" />
>         <br/>
>       </div>
>       <div>
>         <label>Password:</label>
>         <input type="password" name="descr" />
>       </div>
>       <div>
>         <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
>       </div>
>     </form>
```

**Scripts**:

```
window.onload = function () {
var testForm = document.getElementById('loginForm');
testForm.onsubmit = function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    const XHR = new XMLHttpRequest();
    var formData = new FormData(testForm);
    XHR.open( "POST", "http://localhost:5000/addCat", true);
    XHR.setRequestHeader('Content-type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
    XHR.send(formData);
}
}
```

But in **expressjs call**:

```
const addCategories = (request, response) => {
  const { title, descr } = request.body
  console.log(request.body);

// output: { '------WebKitFormBoundaryxBFmvN6Sw8QT3BA7\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name': '"title"\r\n\r\nsdsf\r\n------WebKitFormBoundaryxBFmvN6Sw8QT3BA7\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name="descr"\r\n\r\nsdfdsfds\r\n------WebKitFormBoundaryxBFmvN6Sw8QT3BA7\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name="title"\r\n\r\nnewtitle\r\n------WebKitFormBoundaryxBFmvN6Sw8QT3BA7\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name="descr"\r\n\r\ngoind descriptions\r\n------WebKitFormBoundaryxBFmvN6Sw8QT3BA7--\r\n' }


  client.query('INSERT INTO categoryLists (title, descr) VALUES ($1, $2)', [title, descr], (error, results) => {
    if (error) {
      throw error
    }
    response.status(201).send(`User added with ID: ${results.insertId}`)
  })
};
```

**Getting Error:**
error: null value in column "title" violates not-null constraint

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've said:

> ```
> XHR.setRequestHeader('Content-type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
> ```

… but `FormData` objects generate multipart formatted requests, not urlencoded ones.

Remove that line. Let XHR generate its own `Content-Type` header from the `FormData` object.

---

You also need to make sure that in your Express.js code you have a body parser capable of handling multipart data.

Comment: - Yes, I have removed, but same error. 
- I am using body parser in indexjs file also. 

app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(
    bodyParser.urlencoded({
        extended: true,
    })
); 3. The error throws some connection error also and breaks the app.
  at emitOne (events.js:116:13)
    at TLSSocket.emit (events.js:211:7)
    at addChunk (_stream_readable.js:263:12)
    at readableAddChunk (_stream_readable.js:250:11)
    at TLSSocket.Readable.push (_stream_readable.js:208:10)
    at TLSWrap.onread (net.js:597:20)

Comment: @user3686652 — I said "a body parser capable of handling multipart data" and you are using ones capable of handling JSON encoded data and URL encoded data.

Comment: Using v1.19.0 body parser & JSON, RAW, urlencoded, and text are supportive.

Comment: @user3686652 — You need multipart support! Read the first few paragraphs of the documentation for the [body-parser module](https://www.npmjs.com/package/body-parser)